# Post-apocalyptic book; apocalypse caused by dinosaurs, people live underground

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm looking for a novel, here's what I know:

- It was probably a YA novel.
- Scientists created dinosaurs, which caused an apocalypse.
- The society lives underground, in factions.
- The main character’s father is… missing? Doing something somewhere else?  I’m not sure, I just know that she had to sneak out of the underground city to go to a mail transportation place and look for a letter from her father.  Although this may have been another book in a series, not the first one. I just remember reading a little bit of it, and thinking it was interesting.
- I think the cover had some type of silhouette design, with a green, forest-like background.

Comment: Ahhhhh so this is a sequel book to Jurassic Park? ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Might this be *[The Ark Plan](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26116505-the-ark-plan)* (2016) by Laura Martin, the first book in the *[Edge of Extinction](https://www.goodreads.com/series/185441-edge-of-extinction)* duology...?

The Goodreads synopsis mentions dinsosaurs being cloned and replacing humans at the top of the food chain, humans consequently being forced to move into underground compounds, and a girl whose father has gone missing.

> *Jurassic World* meets *Dawn of the Planet of the Apes* in this epic new middle grade series full of heart-pounding action and breathtaking chills! "Amazing adventures!" raves Brightly.com as they recommend *Edge of Extinction* as a 2016 Holiday Gift for Tween Readers.
>
> **One hundred and fifty years ago, the first dinosaurs were cloned. Soon after, they replaced humans at the top of the food chain. The only way to survive was to move into underground compounds. . . .**
>
> **Five years ago, Sky Mundy’s father vanished from North Compound without a trace.** Now she has just stumbled on a clue that not only suggests his disappearance is just the tip of an even larger mystery, but also points directly to the surface. To find her dad—and possibly even save the world—Sky and her best friend, Shawn, must break out of their underground home and venture topside to a land reclaimed by nature and ruled by dinosaurs.
>
> Perfect for fans of Brandon Mull, Lisa McMann, and Rick Riordan, this exhilarating debut novel follows two courageous friends who must survive in a lost world that’s as dangerous as they’ve always feared but also unlike anything they could ever have imagined.

The cover also features a somewhat silhouetted human figure in the foreground, and a forest in the background.

[image]

[This review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/laura-martin/the-ark-plan/) offers a bit more info on the plot.

> With resurgent dinosaurs roaming the surface, living underground is humanity’s only hope for survival. Or…is it?
>
> **A century and a half ago, scientists revived the dinos à la *Jurassic Park* but also brought on a prehistoric pandemic that wiped out 99.9 percent of the human race. Now Sky (a redheaded white girl, judging by the cover art) lives with less than 100 others in a subterranean bunker that, she has always been told, is the only protection from certain death topside. But on her 12th birthday, a letter from her long-missing father arrives, urging her to deliver a certain flash drive to a mysterious location on Lake Michigan.** She quickly learns not only that there are people maintaining a precarious existence on the surface, but that she’s carrying secrets the supposedly beneficent leaders of her community will kill to suppress. As a budding Katniss Everdeen—tough, stubborn, resilient, and though new to the bow a quick enough learner by the end to put an arrow through the eye of a ravening spinosaurus—Sky makes a promising protagonist. Martin pits her against vividly scary foes both scaled and armed with automatic weapons, places her between two quaintly protective guys (one from aboveground, the other below), and sets her on a path that plainly leads to revelations about her family as well as her world.
>
> Formulaic but with enough juice in the characters and their relentlessly dangerous setting to keep the story hydrated.

Comment: I think that might be it! Thank you!